# Unexpected bit shifting result

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I have:

```
(gdb) display/t raw_data[4]<<8
24: /t raw_data[4]<<8 = 1111100000000
(gdb) display/t raw_data[5]
25: /t raw_data[5] = 11100111
(gdb) display/t (raw_data[4]<<8)|raw_data[5]
26: /t (raw_data[4]<<8)|raw_data[5] = 11111111111111111111111111100111
```

Why is the result on line 26 not `0001111111100111`? Thanks.

edit: More specifically:

```
(gdb) display/t raw_data[5]
27: /t raw_data[5] = 11100111
(gdb) display/t 0|raw_data[5]
28: /t 0|raw_data[5] = 11111111111111111111111111100111
```

Why is the result on line 26 not `11100111`?

Comment: Machine endianness has nothing to do with bit shifting of native integer types. Care to tell us what type `raw_data` is. There is very likely a signed/unsigned promotion at work here.

Comment: char*raw_data is the type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data type is a `char`, which on your platform appears to be signed. The entry `raw_data[5]` holds the negative number -25.

The print format `t` prints the data as unsigned integer in binary. When you print `raw_data[5]`, it is converted to the unsigned char 213, but has only 8 bits. When you do the integer arithmetic on the data, the chars are promoted to a 32-bit integer.

Promoting the negative char value -25 to a signed int will, of course, yield -25, but its representation as an unsigned int is now `2^^32 + x`, whereas as an unsigned char it was `2^^8 + x`. That's where all the ones at the beginning of the 32-bit binary number come from.

It's maybe better to work with unsigned raw data.

Comment: Suggestions on casting to get the results I expect? raw_data[4]<<UINT8_C(8) | raw_data[5]?

Comment: Casting helps, but you have to do it on the shifted value, not on the shift amount. I suggest working with unsogned chars throughout, i.e. make `raw_data` an unsigned type, at least locally. Saves you a lot of worries.

Comment: decided to just go with raw_data[4]<< 8 | (raw_data[5] & 0x00ff);

Comment: @TheoretiCAL: "It's maybe better to work with unsigned [char] data."  This sounds like very good advice to me

Answer (score 2):

Let's just ignore the first block, since the second block is a minimal reproduction.

Also note that `0 | x` preserves the value of `x`, but causes the usual integral promotions.

Then the second block is not so unexpected.

```
(gdb) display/t raw_data[5]
27: /t raw_data[5] = 11100111
```

Ok, `raw_data[5]` is `int8_t(-25)`

```
(gdb) display/t 0|raw_data[5]
28: /t 0|raw_data[5] = 11111111111111111111111111100111
```

and `0|raw_data[5]` is `int(-25)`.  Indeed, the value was preserved.

Answer (score 0):

The constant 8 caused a promotion to a signed integer, so you're seeing sign extension as well at the promotion. Change it to UINT8_C(8). You'll need to include stdint.h for the macro.

Comment: Added #include <stdint.h> but UINT8_C errors on compilation for not being defined in the scope, any ideas?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

UINT8_C is the proper cross platform way of doing it, but you could just use 8U, which would work on just about everything anyway.